# VBA to insert a blank ContentControlPicture at a specific location in Word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I've tried:

```
ActiveDocument.Range.ContentControls.Add (wdContentControlPicture)
```

But I get an error that says "Picture controls cannot be inserted around a selection which contains non-image content, floating images, or more than a single inline image"

I need to insert this control after ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(55) - is there any way to do this?

Comment: The code you show us will try to insert a content control around the entire content of the document. Is that really the code you're using? Try: Dim rng as Word.Range : Set rng = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(55).Range : rng.ContentControls.Add wdContentControlPicture

Comment: @CindyMeister thank you - but I get the same error with the code you've graciously provided. Any other ideas?

Comment: Is the paragraph empty? If not, run this on an *empty* paragraph.